# openCV issue with webcam video feed

Tags: opencv

I have just started getting familiar with openCV, and I have run into a problem while trying basic video processing, using my Laptop's webcam:

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

cap= cv.VideoCapture(0)


while True:
    ret,frame =cap.read()
    
    cv.imshow("frame",frame)
    k=cv.waitKey(0)
    if k==27 :
        break
cap.release()
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

output:

[image]

Clearly, the webcam turned on and the window opened properly, but it isn't showing any feed.

I tried the same code with a downloaded video. ( `cap= cv.VideoCapture("test.mp4")` ), however, the window showed just one, still frame until I exited the program.

What's going wrong with the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**cv2.waitKey(0)** will show a still image so to get a continuous feed you need to do **cv2.waitKey(1)** like below:

```
 k=cv.waitKey(1)
     if k==27 :
         break
```

This solves your second problem and as of your first concern, I think there is an issue with your webcam, test it first.

Now when the video ends, the cv.imshow() will get an empty object inside 'frame' and it will raise an error. To prevent this use a check like this:

```
  ret,frame =cap.read()
  if frame is None:
    break
  cv.imshow("frame",frame)
```

Comment: thanks, that worked, however after the video ended I got this error:                                              ", line 10, in <module>
    cv.imshow("frame",frame)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.1) C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-wvn_it83\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:376: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'cv::imshow'

Comment: Also, the window was destroyed without me pressing enter, but I think thats because of the error..

Comment: @satan29 this error comes when the cv.imshow() function gets an empty object to show. So it is obvious that at the end of the video it receives no capture and throws error, to prevent this error use a check before processing. Let me update my answer

Comment: Thanks. But another problem I'm having is that the video feed is pretty fast forwarded: a 7 second clip only runs for about 1-2 seconds...

Comment: Yes, that's because cv2.waitKey(1) waits for 1ms to show a frame, so increase the delay value a bit and check if you get desired speed. Also, the speed depends on frame rate of the input video. Check your fps by "cap.get(5)"

Comment: 30 fps,, also, I updated waitkey values but beyond a point, they seem to have no effect...the 7 second clip is now being played in 4 seconds for any waitkey value >=4

Comment: 30 fps means 1 frame should be shown for (1/30) sec or 1000/30 mil sec. Try 33 as delay and see if the videos is streaming at normal rate.

Comment: that makes a lot of sense, and it worked. Thanks.